# GPS latitude,longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, maps

I have GPS code for finding latitude,longitude. TouchEvent is very useful.Is any other way for show latitude,longitude on maps application rather than TouchEvent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be very useful to you

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Android/android17MapView.php

Answer (score 1):

Hello check if this helps you :)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LocationManager locationManager;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location =locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);
}
private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {
    String latLongString = "Unknown";
    String addressString = "No address found";
    TextView myLocationText;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.00");  
    myLocationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myLocationText);
    if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        latLongString = "Lat:" +  df.format(lat) + "\nLong:" +  df.format(lng);
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(GPS1Activity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses  = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            if (addresses.size() == 1) {
                addressString="";
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                addressString = addressString + address.getAddressLine(0) + "\n";
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                    addressString = addressString + address.getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                }
                addressString = addressString + address.getLocality()+ "\n";
                addressString = addressString + address.getPostalCode()+ "\n";
                addressString = addressString + address.getCountryName()+ "\n";
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Geocoder IOException exception: ", ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }       
    myLocationText.setText("Your Current Position is:\n" + latLongString + "\n" + addressString);
}
```

Comment: Schewns:I think this tutorial from Retomeier.I have this code only.but i didn't get any output on my emulator

Comment: Schewns: I used this code. Then i send gps coordinates via emulator control.But i didn't get any output from emulator

Comment: this piece of code worked with me, but i remember that at the time there was some problem with the emulator, cause u dont have gps on the emulator. try it with a device.

Comment: let me know if it works for u, if not i can send u all the package, if u send me your email ;)

Comment: karthi51@yahoo.co.in...This is my id, Schewns

Comment: sent, let me know how it went